# I can't use send_keys in Selenium (Python)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to do basic web automation in Python. I am running a test. And I get an error message when I run everything saying:

search.send_keys("Test")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

url = "https://www.youtube.com"

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(3)

search = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='search']")

search.send_keys("Test")
```

How can ı fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"browser.find_elements" gets all the elements with the xpath you sent, returning an array with all the elements that you can then iterate over.

You need to select an individual object instead:

```
search = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='search']")
search.send_keys("Test")
```

If that code doesn't work for you, try using tools like [xPath Finder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-finder/ihnknokegkbpmofmafnkoadfjkhlogph) to grab a unique xPath of the element you want to manipulate.